# Generics when implementing Spring's ConverterFactory with Enums

Tags: java, spring, generics

From the [Spring reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#core-convert-ConverterFactory-SPI), a converter factory can be implemented as follows:

```
final class StringToEnumConverterFactory implements ConverterFactory<String, Enum> {

    public <T extends Enum> Converter<String, T> getConverter(Class<T> targetType) {
        return new StringToEnumConverter(targetType);
    }

    private final class StringToEnumConverter<T extends Enum> implements Converter<String, T> {

        private Class<T> enumType;

        public StringToEnumConverter(Class<T> enumType) {
            this.enumType = enumType;
        }

        public T convert(String source) {
            return (T) Enum.valueOf(this.enumType, source.trim());
        }
    }
}
```

However, `Enum` is a raw type here. If I parameterize `Enum` and have my IDE (`Eclipse Mars`) add the method, it results in the following:

```
final class StringToEnumConverterFactory<T extends Enum<T>> implements ConverterFactory<String, Enum<T>> {


    @Override
    public <T extends Enum<T>> Converter<String, T> getConverter(Class<T> targetType) {
        return new StringToEnumConverter<T>(targetType);
    }

    private final class StringToEnumConverter<T extends Enum<T>> implements Converter<String, T> {

        private Class<T> enumType;

        public StringToEnumConverter(Class<T> enumType) {
            this.enumType = enumType;
        }

        public T convert(String source) {
            return Enum.valueOf(this.enumType, source.trim());
        }
    }

}
```

But now I have two issues:

1. The following compiler error appears:

`The type StringToEnumConverterFactory<T> must implement the inherited abstract method ConverterFactory<String,Enum<T>>.getConverter(Class<T>)`

2. The type parameter `T` is hiding the type `T`.

Can you someone please explain how to properly change the `StringToEnumConverterFactory` to have `Enum` parameterized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually turns out to be (perhaps surprisingly, not sure) a pain in the neck, because of the way `Enum.valueOf` is declared.

To get the example as-is to compile, you'd end up with something like this:

```
class StringToEnumConverterFactory<T extends Enum<T>>
implements ConverterFactory<String, T> {
//                                  ^
    @Override
    public <E extends T> Converter<String, E> getConverter(Class<E> targetType) {
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^                    ^                     ^
        return new StringToEnumConverter<E>(targetType);
//                                       ^
    }
// ...
}
```

This, unfortunately, doesn't actually help us out because then you can only ever have e.g. a `StringToEnumConverterFactory<Planet>` or `StringToEnumConverterFactory<Color>` which defeats the purpose of the generalization the generic method offers. And you won't be able to make a `StringToEnumConverterFactory<?>` or `StringToEnumConverter<Enum<?>>`.

We don't actually want a type variable declared on the class, so the declaration we desire is like this, with a wildcard:

```
class StringToEnumConverterFactory
implements ConverterFactory<String, Enum<?>> {
    @Override
    public <E extends Enum<?>> Converter<String, E> getConverter(
            Class<E> targetType) {
        return new StringToEnumConverter<E>(targetType);
    }
// ...
}
```

But this creates problems for us when we try to call `Enum.valueOf` because its type variable declaration is more restrictive. We won't ever be able to call it without some sort of cowboy unchecked cast (which *is* provably safe, but *only* with `Enum`):

```
return (T) Enum.valueOf((Class) enumType, source);
```

Fortunately, we can still otherwise bypass this through the `Class` object:

```
for (T constant : enumType.getEnumConstants())
    if (constant.name().equals(source))
        return constant;
```

The final code would be something like this:

```
class StringToEnumConverterFactory
implements ConverterFactory<String, Enum<?>> {
    @Override
    public <E extends Enum<?>> Converter<String, E> getConverter(
            Class<E> targetType) {
        return new StringToEnumConverter<E>(targetType);
    }
    static class StringToEnumConverter<E extends Enum<?>>
    implements Converter<String, E> {
        Class<E> enumType;
        StringToEnumConverter(Class<E> enumType) {
            this.enumType = enumType;
        }
        @Override
        public E convert(String source) {
            source = source.trim();
            // perhaps we would cache the constants somewhere
            for (E constant : enumType.getEnumConstants())
                if (constant.name().equals(source))
                    return constant;
            // also some people like to return null
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(source);
        }
    }
}
```

So no raw types, no unchecked casts, but kind of a pain in the neck.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may not be possible to define a converter factory as you are trying to do. The type you really want is a `ConverterFactory<String, R>`, where `R extends Enum<R>`. Note that I have used the type `R` here to match [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConverterFactory.html), in order to avoid confusion.

The API of the `ConverterFactory` interface then requires us to implement the following method:

```
public <T extends R> Converter<String, T> getConverter(Class<T> targetType) {
    ???
}
```

We know that it is in fact impossible to extend enum types, and therefore the only possibility is that `T` and `R` are the same type. However this is not known by the compiler, and therefore we cannot make any other assertions about the type `T` other than that it extends `R`.

In particular, we do not know whether `T extends Enum<T>`. We therefore cannot use `T` in a `StringToEnumConverter<T>` as you have defined it, since we cannot use `Class<T>` in `Enum.valueOf`.

I think you therefore need to continue using the original version without generics. It is slightly unfortunate that it requires an unchecked cast, but keep in mind that generics are erased at compile time, so all that will be left is a cast to `Enum` anyway.